# Org-babel remote inline images with TRAMP not exporting in org export

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tramp, org-babel

I am trying to find a way to get the images generated in my remote server exported to a HTML locally. Orgmode of a local analysis works as expected, but if I have tramp enabled with:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args R :dir "/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder" :session R-ea-server :exports both :cache yes
```

Then something like this won't work when I print out the report with org-export html:

```
#+header: :width 1500 :height 1000 :res 150 :type cairo
#+BEGIN_SRC R :exports both :session R-ea-server  :dir "/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder" :results output graphics file :file graphs/missing.png
# deselect all genetic PCs from 4 to 10 for both twins
dt %>%
  select(-c(genetic_pc_4_T1:genetic_pc_10_T1, genetic_pc_4_T2:genetic_pc_10_T2)) %>%
  vis_miss(.)
#+end_src



#+RESULTS[a25483d148e45469ed82d0fbfc16235de2deee8b]:
[[file:/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder/graphs/missing.png]]
```

The image above is "cached" by TRAMP locally and is displayed normally in Emacs.

- Is there a way to make the TRAMP locally saved image show up in the printed report?

Comment: "..won't work": in what way? I ssh to localhost (I don't have a second physical machine  -or a VM - running), but that works, in the sense that evaluating the source block produces an image with an error message `could not find function "%>%` centered on the image. When I export to HTML, I get an `<img src="file://ssh:nick@localhost:/home/nick/folder/graphs/missing.png" alt="missing.png" />` in the HTML file and when I view the file in my browser, the image is there. So I'm not sure what you are talking about, but I guess I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: In the case of a remote server the image does not load

Comment: Does the image load in your browser if you use `localhost` but still with the `ssh` protocol?